# Можно ли использовать $className::$methodName()?

Tags: php, ооп

мне приходит вебхук в котором лежит json вида

```
{
...
  "itemId":"id"
  "itemType":"foo", // "bar", "buzz", etc.
  "event":"update", // "create", "delete", etc.
  "data":{},
...
}
```

это удобно обрабатывать статическими методами типа

```
<?php
Bar::create($json);
Foo::update($json);
/**********************/
Class Foo {
  public static updateItem($json) {
    $foo = Foo::findMethod($json->itemId);
    $foo->updateData($json->data);
    etc.

  }

  public static deleteItem($json) {
    $foo = Foo::findMethod($json->itemId);
    $foo->delete();
  }
}
```

собственно вопрос:
насколько нормальным будет использовать конструктор метода типа

```
<?php
$className = $jsonReader->getClassName($json); //returns 'Foo'
$methodName = $jsonReader->getMethodName($json); //return 'updateItem'
if (method_exists($className, $methodNаme) {
  $classNAme::methodName($json);
}
```

или лучше использовать гирлянды ифов

```
if ($json->itemName == 'foo') {
  switch ($json->event) {
    case 'create':
     Foo::createItem($json);
     break;
    case 'update':
     Foo::updateItem($json);
     break;
    //etc.
  }
} else if ($json->itemName == 'bar') {
  switch ($json->event) {
    case 'create':
     Bar::createItem($json);
     break;
    case 'update':
     Bar::updateItem($json);
     break;
    //etc.
  }
} //etc.
```

какие есть плюсы-минусы?
или ваши варианты?

Comment: 5-ть строк в сравнении с 20-ю строками -- разве не очевидно, __что__ лучше использовать?

Comment: оно-то очевидно, я и использую))
воспрос насколько такой подход является нормальным в плане читаемости кода, обслуживания и т.п.

потому что можно что угодно в одну строку написать))

Comment: Ифы раздувают код, в пыхточке - лучше юзать динамику на полную катушку. Кому понадобится, тот разберется, если не нупь кончено.